# Post data with url variable using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a Follow/unfollow button which is working perfectly with PHP. How do i write ajax to follow/unfollow without page refresh and update the button value(follow or unfollow) accordingly?

PHP:

```
//FOLLOW
if(isset($_POST['follow'])){

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `follows`(`user_id`, `following_id`) VALUES ('$Sessionid','$getID')");
header("Location: /funaholic/profile?Profileid=$getID");
}

//UNFOLLOW
if(isset($_POST['unfollow'])){

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `follows` WHERE  user_id=$Sessionid AND following_id=$getID");
header("Location: /funaholic/profile?Profileid=$getID");
}

//CHECK IF ALREADY FOLLOWING

$getFollowing = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `follows` WHERE user_id='$Sessionid' AND following_id='$getID'");

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($getFollowing);

if($rowcount === 0){
  if($Sessionid == $getID){
     echo "<form action='update' id='followform' method='POST'>
            <button class='follow' name='follow'>UDATE PROFILE</button>
           </form>";
}else {
     echo "<form action='profile?Profileid=".$getID."' id='followform' method='POST'>
            <button class='follow' id='myBTN' name='follow'>FOLLOW</button>
           </form>";
           }

}else{
     echo "<form action='profile?Profileid=".$getID."' method='POST'>
            <button class='follow' id='myBTN' name='unfollow'>UNFOLLOW</button>
           </form>";
}
```

AND THIS IS THE AJAX POST FUNCTION:

```
        //FOLLOW UNFOLLOW AJAX
        $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:  $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
            alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });

        });

        });
```

Comment: "How do i write ajax"...well you've already written some. Is there a more specific question / problem we can help you with? Please be precise about what you need to ask us about. It _looks like_ your probably may be that you aren't using the output from the AJAX call to update the buttons in your page? Is that your issue? Or anything else?

Comment: what i mean is this ajax code is not working. What would be the solution? on button click i get the alert 'form was submitted' but php code doesnt execute

Comment: if you get the alert, then that means the AJAX was successful. That in turn means that some part of the PHP was definitely executed. have you actually used your browser's Network tool to examine what specific response you get from the AJAX call? Open your developer tools, go to Network, then submit your form...you should see an AJAX/XHR call going to `/profile`. Click on it and then open the Response tab which appears. Check the contents. I expect it contains some HTML. The problem is that you're not doing anything with that HTML when it's returned to your "success" method...

Comment: ...I would guess that you haven't correctly understood how AJAX works and you're expecting it to somehow automatically show that data on your page? But logically,how could it? How would it know where in your page to show the HTML that's being echoed? Where would it fit, inside the content which is already there, and hasn't gone away (unlike in a normal form postback)? No, your "success" method needs to contain some JavaScript code which takes the returned data and inserts it into the correct part of the page (and maybe removes any other content which is no longer needed).

Comment: i tried console.log with the url and data. I get this error:-
Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
    at Object.success (profile?Profileid=2:139)
    at c (VM388 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM388 jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (VM388 jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM388 jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: maybe the problem is with my data as it says serialize but one of my data comes from session variable set with php and other one comes from Profile url

Comment: I literally have no idea what you are on about. What URL? What data? Your PHP echoes some HTML button data. You need to receive it and put it somewhere in your page . E.g. `success: function (response) { $("#someDiv").html(response); }`. You can find examples of this concept in dozens of tutorials etc online. Have you not studied any examples? Did you not do what I said to try and examine the real response?